# Vue - Extract multiple components from index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a Vue.js project that uses the .vue component specs format when writing components for my project (see example below). What i noticed, is that plain JavaScript can export these components loaded from vue files. For example, index.js can export an component defined in index.vue. What I'm trying to do now is export multiple components from the index.js. However, when i import the multiple components, they do not render. If i import the index.js as a single object, and then extract the components, it works correctly. Why/How can't i extract multiple components from index?

index.js

```
import A from './A.vue';
import B from './A.vue';

export default { A,  B };
```

home.vue

```
<script>
import Main from "../common/forms";
const { A, B } = Main; // Works 
// import { A, B } from "../common/forms"; // Not Working 


export default {
    name: 'app-home',
    components:{ A, B}
}
</script>
<template>
    <div id="app-home">
        <h1>App Home </h1>      
        <A /> 
        <B/>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misinterpret `import { A, B }` as object destructuring, but it is not.

This codet tries to import the values A and B that were exported as such. Like for instance:

```
export class A {}
export class B {}
```

But you are exporting your object as the default export.

If you want to export both components and not the object as whole, you can use

```
export { A,  B }
```

which allows you to use `import { A, B }`.

It is worth checking out [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).